Surprisingly high latency for Rust's `sync_all` on macOS
Context
With the goal in mind to explore the domain of data persistence, I am trying to write a (very) simple networked service:

A client sends some data to a server.
The server writes the data to disk.
The server replies "ok" to the client.

In my example, the data is very important and should not be lost. Upon receiving the "ok" signal from the server, the client deletes its local copy of the data, trusting that the server holds a copy. This setting is described in an excellent article that led me to the discovery of fsync. If I understand correctly, fsync instructs the operating system to persist to disk all outstanding data on a given file descriptor. Once fsync returns, data is safely stored.
My favorite language is Rust, so that is what I turned to to implement this example. To the best of my understanding, fsync's equivalent in Rust is sync_all, so that is what I set out to use. The basic logic of my server would be:

Receive the data from the client.
Write the data to a File.
Invoke sync_all on the File, wait for it to return.
Send back "ok" to the client.

A surprising benchmark
Before even setting to write my network code, I started with a trivial benchmark:
use rand::RngCore;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::{Seek, SeekFrom, Write};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn main() {
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("hello.dat")
        .expect("Failed to open file");

    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)); // Wait for a moment after opening the file

    for i in 0u32..100 {
        let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 1024];
        rand::thread_rng().fill_bytes(&mut buffer);

        let start_time = Instant::now();

        file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0))
            .expect("Failed to seek to the beginning of the file");

        file.write_all(&buffer).expect("Failed to write to file");

        file.sync_all().expect("Failed to sync to file");

        let elapsed_time = start_time.elapsed();
        println!("Time taken for write {}: {:?}", i, elapsed_time,);
    }
}

The benchmark simply opens a File, writes 1 KB and invokes sync_all, measuring how long the process takes and repeating the measurement 100 times.
I ran the code on my 2024 Macbook Pro M3 Max, which uses an Apple AP2048Z SSD. To my dismay, the benchmark measured approximately 4ms per write. Such a long time defeats my intuition: how can a write to a local, modern SSD take several times longer than, e.g., pinging google.com? Surprised, I checked online to understand what latency one could expect of an SSD. A quick search led me to this article reporting that the average write latency for even a QLC SSD should hover around 70 microseconds. That is nearly 60 times less than what I am observing.
I am wondering what is happening? My intuition suggests that writing some small amount of data to disk (I tried with a single byte all the way to a few megabytes, the time to return from sync_all is always the same, around 4ms) should take an amount of time comparable to the SSD's write latency. In fact, in my mind, that is what write latency aims to measure!
[UPDATE 1] Additional data
To get a grasp of what might be going on, I installed and ran fio on my system:
 % fio --name=latency_benchmark --fdatasync=1 --ioengine=posixaio --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --numjobs=1 --size=1G --runtime=1m --time_based
latency_benchmark: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=posixaio, iodepth=1
fio-3.37
Starting 1 process
latency_benchmark: Laying out IO file (1 file / 1024MiB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [w(1)][100.0%][w=134MiB/s][w=34.2k IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
latency_benchmark: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=96200: Sat Jun 15 14:02:44 2024
  write: IOPS=27.5k, BW=108MiB/s (113MB/s)(6455MiB/60001msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (nsec): min=0, max=705000, avg=689.65, stdev=791.16
    clat (nsec): min=0, max=5391.0k, avg=13040.05, stdev=52330.03
     lat (usec): min=4, max=5392, avg=13.73, stdev=52.34
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[    6],  5.00th=[    6], 10.00th=[    6], 20.00th=[    6],
     | 30.00th=[    6], 40.00th=[    6], 50.00th=[    8], 60.00th=[    9],
     | 70.00th=[    9], 80.00th=[    9], 90.00th=[   10], 95.00th=[   12],
     | 99.00th=[  143], 99.50th=[  155], 99.90th=[  229], 99.95th=[ 1500],
     | 99.99th=[ 2040]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=23675, max=152578, per=100.00%, avg=110181.21, stdev=40310.33, samples=119
   iops        : min= 5918, max=38144, avg=27544.97, stdev=10077.64, samples=119
  lat (nsec)   : 2=0.01%
  lat (usec)   : 2=0.02%, 4=0.01%, 10=90.64%, 20=5.33%, 50=0.03%
  lat (usec)   : 100=0.31%, 250=3.56%, 500=0.02%, 750=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.06%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%
  fsync/fdatasync/sync_file_range:
    sync (nsec): min=0, max=7069.0k, avg=21486.12, stdev=16450.76
    sync percentiles (nsec):
     |  1.00th=[17024],  5.00th=[17024], 10.00th=[17024], 20.00th=[18048],
     | 30.00th=[18048], 40.00th=[19072], 50.00th=[20096], 60.00th=[21888],
     | 70.00th=[22912], 80.00th=[23936], 90.00th=[27008], 95.00th=[30080],
     | 99.00th=[34048], 99.50th=[36096], 99.90th=[42752], 99.95th=[50944],
     | 99.99th=[82432]
  cpu          : usr=6.37%, sys=12.88%, ctx=3305893, majf=0, minf=9
  IO depths    : 1=200.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,1652467,0,0 short=1652467,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=108MiB/s (113MB/s), 108MiB/s-108MiB/s (113MB/s-113MB/s), io=6455MiB (6769MB), run=60001-60001msec

I have to admit I am not too competent at orienting myself in fio's output (for example, I am not entirely sure what the difference is between slat, clat and lat). But, it seems to me that the average write latency when writing 4 KB should be around 14 us, and the time to sync around 21 us.
I might have run my test incorrectly here? If so, please do point that out. If I didn't, then I am not sure where the very large discrepancy I observe comes from.
[UPDATE 2] Experiment on a Linux server
I starting to wonder if there might be something at play here, maybe related to Rust's standard library targeting Apple Silicon. I ran the same fio on a cheap Linux server I am renting, getting strictly worse latency (avg. 68 us) and similar fsync timing (avg. 22 us).
However, running the exact same benchmark, compiled on the same version of the rust compiler, with the same optimization flags, the time fluctuates between 25 and 50 us. This is between 80 and 160 times less! I will try to run the same test on the same machine using C, as suggested by @user2407038.
[UPDATE 3] Switching to C
It's not Rust's fault. I tried to translate the above Rust code to C. I hope I got it right:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("hello.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return 1;
    }

    sleep(1); // Wait for a moment after opening the file

    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
            buffer[j] = rand() % 256;
        }

        gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);

        if (lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to seek to the beginning of the file");
            return 1;
        }

        if (write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != sizeof(buffer)) {
            perror("Failed to write to file");
            return 1;
        }

        if (fcntl(fd, F_FULLFSYNC) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to sync to file");
            return 1;
        }

        gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
        long elapsed_time = ((end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) * 1000000L) + end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec;

        printf("Time taken for write %d: %ld microseconds\n", i, elapsed_time);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

Note in particular how I'm using fcntl(fd, F_FULLFSYNC) instead of fsync(fd), as fsync on OSX apparently does not guarantee that the data is actually flushed to disk. I get a very similar behavior: around 4ms of measured latency. This is baffling, but also interesting!
[UPDATE 4] Going with fsync
In the above snippet, if I switch fcntl(fd, F_FULLSYNC) for fsync(fd) the measured time collapses to 30 us, more than 100 times less than using F_FULLSYNC.

You're not just measuring sync_all though, you're measuring seek + write_all + sync_all … And even then, sync_all takes the time to write everything not yet written + the latency, I'm not sure how you'd measure the write latency, but timing sync_all aint it.

Measuring just sync_all does not affect the results. The other two operations (seek + write_all) together take around 5 microsecond. Thank you for pointing that out though!

Also writing to files on disk has all the overhead of the file system (updating time stamps, updating metadata, updating the write log, ...), so it will have an impact to the times you see as well.

I added the results of some very naive benchmarks I did with fio. Even while syncing, it seems to take much less? Do you think that fio might be using a different command from the one I am using?

You could try to profile your code to have a clearer picture of what's taking most of the time, although with such a short execution I'm not sure whether you'll be able to collect very precise timings.

Disk drive latency is NOT the time between an operation being initiated and it being completed. It is the time between being initiated (calling the syscall) and when the driver reports "your operation is valid or an error". Writes of any size have the same latency (all other things being equal) because the data to be written is buffered. This is exactly why fsync is a useful operation - it lets you wait until no more buffered data remains. I don't think there is any promptness guarantee with fsync so this speed seems reasonable. Can you try the same program in C to compare?

I do wonder if something else is going on (not Rust related). My drive has worse latency and throughput reported by fio, but running this code says it takes 500-700us to do the seek, write, and sync.

Can you try using File::sync_data() instead of File::sync_all()? That I think it corresponds to the infamous fdatasync() POSIX function.

@rodrigo Tried that as well, the result is identical!

@kmdreko are you also running on OSX?

@user2407038 As I wrote in Update 3, it seems that switching from Rust to C has no effect.

@MatteoMonti no, my numbers are from windows

Yeah, on Linux I get 30 micros on a less performant SSD than mine (at least according to fio).

Why is F_FULLFSYNC slower than fsync?
This question is actually fairly simple to answer. As you found in your research, F_FULLFSYNC simply does more stuff than fsync. Here is a quote from the man pages on fsync.

https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/2/fsync/
For applications that require tighter guarantees about the integrity of their data, Mac OS X provides the F_FULLFSYNC fcntl.  The F_FULLFSYNC fcntl asks the drive to flush all buffered data to permanent storage.  Applications, such as databases, that require a strict ordering of writes should use F_FULLFSYNC to ensure that their data is written in the order they expect.  Please see fcntl(2) for more detail.

If we dig into the Rust standard library, we see it uses F_FULLFSYNC, so that explains the results you saw in your C comparison.
    pub fn fsync(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        cvt_r(|| unsafe { os_fsync(self.as_raw_fd()) })?;
        return Ok(());

        #[cfg(any(
            target_os = "macos",
            target_os = "ios",
            target_os = "tvos",
            target_os = "watchos",
        ))]
        unsafe fn os_fsync(fd: c_int) -> c_int {
            libc::fcntl(fd, libc::F_FULLFSYNC)
        }
        #[cfg(not(any(
            target_os = "macos",
            target_os = "ios",
            target_os = "tvos",
            target_os = "watchos",
        )))]
        unsafe fn os_fsync(fd: c_int) -> c_int {
            libc::fsync(fd)
        }
    }

Why is F_FULLFSYNC so slow?
Many modern hard drives (particularly SSDs) will perform journaling of writes before committing them to the disk. This is done in hardware and helps to reduce power consumption and improve overall performance by grouping together writes to the same blocks of memory. My guess is that the overhead you are seeing may be related to the commit interval due to the small write size.
(See edit below for more information) Now, this is the point where I wanted to show a nice graph displaying real world benchmark data that backs up my claim by letting us see the commit interval in relation to write sizes. I had planned to spin up a mac ec2 instance to run it, but it turns out those are way more expensive than had I initially thought (>$1/hr, minimum 24h). Instead, here is what it looks like on some other machines. They arn't directly related to your use case, but I think the results are still interesting.
That being said, without the benchmark data or an authoritative source, I can not be 100% certain this is the primary cause of the performance difference.
Windows1 Results (Benchmark Source)
x64 Windows 11 Pro 23H2 with 1T NTFS SSD

Linux VM Results2 (Benchmark Source)
x64 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with 20GB ext4 NVMe SSD (Digital Ocean Droplet)

1 Technically Windows uses FlushFileBuffers, not fsync or F_FULLFSYNC.
2 This graph is a bit choppier because the benchmark ran for only ~1/8 the duration of the Windows machine.

Edit
After additional searching, I stumbled across Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach. This book goes into depth on the implementation of F_FULLFSYNC in HFS+ (the predecessor of APFS that is in use today). If you are interested, consider reading these sections of the book. Based on what I have read so far, I suspect the delay occurs in ioctl(disk, DKIOCSYNCHRONIZECACHE) (and by extension maybe the doSynchronizeCache() function of the disk driver). However, I have not yet been able to confirm this to be the case (I need to figure out how to work around Apple's sandboxing to run this operation directly).

Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach  By Amit Singh
Chapter 12, Page 1540

FIGURE 12-23 Processing of the F_FULLSYNC file control operation

Additionally, I decided to run the benchmark on a MAC from work and got the following result. This machine should be similar to the one used for the original question.
Apple M3 Pro (Benchmark Source)
MacOS Sonoma 14.5 with 1T APFS SSD

What is really surprising to me is just how consistent the timing is. It isn't about 4ms, it is 4ms. Or to be more precise, about 3955±15μs3 (Raw Benchmark Data). In the graph you can see that up until around 40k, the line corresponding to the seek time is almost perfectly horizontal. This has been extremely consistent in all of the runs. With such reliable timing, I am suspicious the disk driver might be sleeping for a fixed time period (or some other clock-dependent approach to waiting for flush to complete).
3 I later realized that my previous assertion about the consistency of the F_FULLSYNC durations was flawed. The way I wrote the benchmark, the result for a given run is the median of multiple samples. This helps filter out outliers, but reduces overall variation. The correct interpretation should have been that "F_FULLSYNC following writes smaller than ~40KB had a median duration of 3955±15μs as measured across 125 samples/write size".
Edit 2
I went back and put together a new graph showing the distribution of individual samples. This graph consists of 10000 samples per write size sorted in ascending order (Raw Data). I cherry-picked a couple write sizes to reduce the overall clutter, but there are more in the full data. Of the samples taken, the shortest F_FULLFSYNC took 3256.792μs, however this was an extreme outlier with only 1% of samples being under 3609μs.

I also wanted to say that this is probably as far as I can go looking into this problem. While I am still curious as to the exact cause, I have no experience profiling kernel drivers and I do not want to mess with the security settings of work laptops to try and figure it out.

That is really impressive! Thank you so much for the effort!! What I can't wrap my head around, however, is why my fio reports around 21 us to sync, versus the 4 ms my code experiences. I even checked fio's source, they do use F_FULLSYNC. I even recompiled fio to make sure F_FULLSYNC was enabled by ./configure. It seems to me like we have two pieces of code, both of which use F_FULLSYNC, but one is 190 times faster than the other.

I hypothesized for a moment that it might be due to more writes coming quickly from fio to fill whatever queue the disk might want to fill before flushing. But then I remembered that fio, just like my code, invokes F_FULLSYNC every time it writes a block (--fdatasync=1). So, in my head, that does not explain it either!

I feel this doesn't answer the question. If in other OSes fsync() can do that and in less time, why does it take so much time in macOS? And if other platforms' fsync() don't do that, why does Rust's stdlib uses fcntl() on macOS instead of fsync()?

@ChayimFriedman, ...other platforms' fsync() doesn't do that. Presumably, though, if those platforms offered something with the stronger guarantees MacOS makes available, then the slower/safer thing would be used on those other platforms as well.

@CharlesDuffy If that is the case, then I believe Rust's stdlib choice is wrong, no matter how you look at it. I opened a Zulip discussion.

@CharlesDuffy ...in which bjorn3 responded that in Linux fsync does flush, which brings back the question - what's taking so long?

Eh. Whether fsync() flushes all the way to hardware depends on exactly which hardware you have. Granted, it was about 20 years since I was doing work where I needed to have all the details in my head, and things may have changed / gotten better since then, but back then if you weren't using hardware designed for safety over performance (or with price-is-no-object features like a write cache with a battery to ensure it could be flushed) it was very possible to have content flushed with fsync() not visible after a power failure.

@CharlesDuffy The docs claim: "fsync() transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data of (i.e., modified buffer cache pages for) the file referred to by the file descriptor fd to the disk device (or other permanent storage device) so that all changed information can be retrieved even if the system crashes or is rebooted.  This includes writing through or flushing a disk cache if present.  The call blocks until the device reports that the transfer has completed." (emphasis mine). If this is correct, I don't think you are right.

Right, that's how it works in theory. I'm just saying that practice has historically differed. (There are other complications, like needing to fsync() containing directories if a file that was just flushed was created/renamed, but those are a separate matter).

@ChayimFriedman, that is not correct. Those are the man pages for Linux. The OSX man pages have extremely weak claims for fsync and state "Note that while fsync() will flush all data from the host to the drive (i.e. the "permanent storage device"), the drive itself may not physically write the data to the platters for quite some time and it may be written in an out-of-order sequence. Specifically, if the drive loses power or the OS crashes, the application may find that only some or none of their data was written."

@Locke But that is exactly what I want to know: if Linux manages to provide the same guarantees in much less time, what's taking so long for macOS?

Note: T2 and later Mac internal flash drives are known to be slow at executing F_FULLSYNC (you can see marcan_42's comment in a Hackers News thread. Even external drives hooked up over USB are faster at completing F_FULLSYNC. So it's not so much a macOS problem and more a Mac internal flash problem.
